# Scrolling of UITableview change the images of UIButton , UITableview scrolling issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

What i am doing is , I have an `UITableview` and i added `UIButton` as a custom view . I am giving tag to each button and **tag** got received in the action method. When i press the button it change the images for selected and unselected button but when i scroll it , it will come to normal state.

**This is my cell for row at index method**

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell4";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [self tableviewCellWithReuseIdentifierFollowing:CellIdentifier];
}
followingButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[followingButton addTarget:self action:@selector(followingButtonpressed:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[followingButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"following12.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
followingButton.frame = CGRectMake(220.0 ,20.0, 100, 40.0);
[cell.contentView addSubview:followingButton];
NSLog(@"row--%d",indexPath.row);
followingButton.tag=indexPath.row;
NSLog(@"followingButton.tag--%d",followingButton.tag);
[self configureCellFollowing:cell forIndexPath:indexPath];
return cell;
}

==================

//Here is the action method

-(void)followingButtonpressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"sender tag --%d",[sender tag]);
    UIButton *btnPly = (UIButton *)sender;
    if([btnPly isSelected])
    {
        [btnPly setSelected:NO];
        [btnPly setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"following12.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [btnPly setSelected:YES];
        [btnPly setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"following_off12.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you ever figuredout how to solve this issue? I have the same issue right now,.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note : This code create cell for each row of data (Not reuse cell)**

You need to change only as describe , May be helpful for you

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

**may be solve your problem :)**

Comment: Thanks ... Thanks so much . I was doing this since 8 hours and now i got this done . Really thankfull to you

Comment: Keep in mind this solution might cause performance issues as your table grows in size.  The best solution is to have a data source manage your state, that way you can still keep the cell reuse performance.

Comment: @Nebs - issues is create when user have long data ...but i also put *NOTE* in my answer (*it is not reuse `UITableViewCell`*) it will create cell for each row

Answer (score 2):

The reason your buttons are "resetting" is because tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called multiple times (whenever a cell is about to be visible).

Each time this gets called you are reinitializing your button and resetting the image to following12.png (the default state).  That's why when you scroll the buttons appear to reset.

You can't rely on the cell itself to preserve state because the cell will get reset every time.  You need to move your state somewhere else (like in an array instance variable).  Then when you have to configure a new cell in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath you can initialize it to the proper state (based on the array).

So create an NSMutableArray instance variable called myStateArray (or whatever) to store your button states, then your cellForRowAtIndexPath should look more like:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell4";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [self tableviewCellWithReuseIdentifierFollowing:CellIdentifier];
}
followingButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[followingButton addTarget:self action:@selector(followingButtonpressed:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// -- Fetch the state from your array
BOOL buttonPressed = [[self.myStateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];

// -- Initialize the button state correctly
[followingButton setSelected:buttonPressed];
if (buttonPressed) {
    [followingButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"following12.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} else {
    [followingButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"following_off12.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}



followingButton.frame = CGRectMake(220.0 ,20.0, 100, 40.0);
[cell.contentView addSubview:followingButton];
NSLog(@"row--%d",indexPath.row);
followingButton.tag=indexPath.row;
NSLog(@"followingButton.tag--%d",followingButton.tag);
[self configureCellFollowing:cell forIndexPath:indexPath];
return cell;
}
```

Then in your button press make sure to save the state:

```
-(void)followingButtonpressed:(id)sender
{
    // -- Save the state
    [self.myStateArray insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:[btnPly isSelected]] atIndex:[sender tag]];

    NSLog(@"sender tag --%d",[sender tag]);
    UIButton *btnPly = (UIButton *)sender;
    if([btnPly isSelected])
    {
        [btnPly setSelected:NO];
        [btnPly setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"following12.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [btnPly setSelected:YES];
        [btnPly setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"following_off12.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please suggest where you write that statement?

Comment: @Prateeksharma I've updated my answer with some sample code (it's not tested, but just to give you an idea).

Comment: tried this way too with array , but again when i scroll it removes current state and put it into normal state

Comment: @Prateeksharma Are you sure?  Did you make sure to initialize the array and update it when the button is pressed?  Put some logs in your cellForRowAtIndexPath and print the row index as well as the value of the array at that index.  Also what does your configureCellFollowing method do?  Does it override the state of the button?  Post that method in your original question if you can.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand from code you create UIButton every time when UITableView asks for cell. In both cases if you create a new cell or you use dequeued one. Then you create and add one more button every time over already created one. Move button creation to cell creation `if` So your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method should looks like

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell4";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [self tableviewCellWithReuseIdentifierFollowing:CellIdentifier];
        followingButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [followingButton addTarget:self action:@selector(followingButtonpressed:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [followingButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"following12.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        followingButton.frame = CGRectMake(220.0 ,20.0, 100, 40.0);
        [cell.contentView addSubview:followingButton];
    }
    NSLog(@"row--%d",indexPath.row);
    followingButton.tag=indexPath.row;
    NSLog(@"followingButton.tag--%d",followingButton.tag);
    [self configureCellFollowing:cell forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

But this will not be competed solution of your problem. As you probably know UITableView uses "reusable" cells to decrease system memory usage. It uses only amount of cells as it necessary to show at the moment. So in table with 100 cells it will create actually about 10. And all of them wont store correct state of all amount pressed/unpressed buttons. To achieve correct behaviour you have to refuse using tags and use some model logic instead. Easiest way - NSMutableArray where you will store buttons states.  In  `followingButtonpressed:` method you will set proper object to YES/NO and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you will read this value.
Check code below

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell4";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [self tableviewCellWithReuseIdentifierFollowing:CellIdentifier];
        followingButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [followingButton addTarget:self action:@selector(followingButtonpressed:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [followingButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"following12.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        followingButton.frame = CGRectMake(220.0 ,20.0, 100, 40.0);
        [cell.contentView addSubview:followingButton];

        BOOL isSelected = [[statesArray objectAtIndex:btnPly.tag] boolValue];
        [self setState:isSelected forButton:followingButton];
    }
    NSLog(@"row--%d",indexPath.row);
    followingButton.tag=indexPath.row;
    NSLog(@"followingButton.tag--%d",followingButton.tag);
    [self configureCellFollowing:cell forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

-(void)followingButtonpressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"sender tag --%d",[sender tag]);
    UIButton *btnPly = (UIButton *)sender;

    BOOL isSelected = [[statesArray objectAtIndex:btnPly.tag] boolValue];
    [statesArray replaceObjectAtIndex:btnPly.tag withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!isSelected]];

    if(isSelected)
    {
        [self setState:NO forButton:btnPly];
    }
    else
    {
        [self setState:YES forButton:btnPly];
    }
}

- (void) setState:(BOOL)state forButton:(UIButton *)button
{
    if(state)
    {
        [button setSelected:NO];
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"following12.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [button setSelected:YES];
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"following_off12.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Where `statesArray` is

```
NSMutableArray *statesArray = [NSMutableArray new];
```

and you have to create and initialize it somewhere in you class. Count of objects in `statesArray` has to be the same as count of cells int tableView.

Comment: [self tableviewCellWithReuseIdentifierFollowing:CellIdentifier];this where you implemented.

Answer (score 0):

This is because every time when you are scrolling then this code calling

```
[followingButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"following12.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

so check now

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell4";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [self tableviewCellWithReuseIdentifierFollowing:CellIdentifier];

followingButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[followingButton addTarget:self action:@selector(followingButtonpressed:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[followingButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"following12.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

followingButton.frame = CGRectMake(220.0 ,20.0, 100, 40.0);
[cell.contentView addSubview:followingButton];

[self configureCellFollowing:cell forIndexPath:indexPath];
}
return cell;
}
```

Comment: Tried it , but its not solving the problem , On scrolling its again change the image to normal state